# Adding If/Else to WordPress php

Tags: php, wordpress

Over the past few weeks I have been learning very quickly some of the tricks and traps of messing with someone else's coding - I'm trying to customise a WordPress theme that's almost perfect for the project I'm working on but not quite.  It's the closest I've found though after much searching and so I'm working on making some small (in my opinion) adjustments to the theme so that it suits better.

In a nutshell, there is an integrated "membership" function that allows members who have paid create a post and members who have not paid to only view said posts.  If don't sign up for a membership then you can't view the posts.

As is common there is a Profile page with a great sidebar that includes links to various reports as well as to a summary of the posts made and historic invoices for the paid members.

My issue is that those are all displayed for the "free" Members too because in reality the theme has been set up with just one single Account type which means any change you make for the free members also impacts on the paid ones too.

The conclusion I have come to is that there must be a way to "hide" or not display a particular element if certain conditions are not met by the user.  In my case I'm thinking that the easiest approach would be to use the argument IF there are no payments associated with the profile the page should not display the relevant sections.

MY problem is that I'm dealing with a new area for me and getting my head around it isn't quite working - on top of that the coding for WordPress is a quite specific and again I've not quite grasped it all enough to feel confident with what I'm doing.

I'm happy to post some exisiting code but I wouldn't know what it would be that could be useful for anyone to see at this point - especially if I've got the whole thing wrong and I'm approaching it the wrong way!

Many thanks in advance for any and all helpful responses!

Answer (score 0):

You may study with the UserPro Wp Plugin for these kinds of problems. Download **UserPro** and **UserPro Dashboard** Plugin then study with these plugins, hopefully you will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that however looking at the specifications of those concerns me that it would over-ride everything that already is featured within the theme I am using and I don't want to do that.  I can see how your solution would be great for another project I've got in the pipeline though so I am grateful for you sharing that with me!

Comment: @GrandView Thank you, hopefully, you will get a solution.